# HTML cell DOM get attribute value - sort table.js

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, sorttable.js

I'm trying to make the sorttable.js to read values from a custom tr attribute, which is "sort_value".

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="sort_string">Name</th>
            <th class="sort_int">Age</th>
            <th class="sort_int">Date of Birth</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Adam</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td sort_value="19930403">April 3 1993</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Matt</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td sort_value="19950220">Feb 20 1995</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Josh</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td sort_value="19900730">July 30 1990</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kent</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td sort_value="19880322">March 22 1988</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zz4mugen/6/

Everything is perfect except the date of birth column. Please take a look at the .js of the jsfiddle. It's on the external resources column.

Answer (score 0):

You're using custom attributes, but the name is not valid. Own attributes have to start with data-. See the official documentation: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes

Below an interesting blog with explanation and examples about sorting different types of values in tables, such as numbers, texts, currencies and dates for different locales.

https://yoast.com/articles/sortable-table/#example